# React async doesn't trigger rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

```js
const AUTH_DISABLED = 0;
const AUTH_LOGIN = 1;
const AUTH_LOGOUT = 2;

function App() {
  const [showLoginPopup, setShowLoginPopup] = useState(false);
  const [authButtonState, setAuthButtonState] = useState(AUTH_DISABLED);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if ( authButtonState == AUTH_LOGOUT ) {
      authGlobal.logout().then( () => { setAuthButtonState(AUTH_LOGIN) } );
    } else {
      setShowLoginPopup(true)
    }
  };

    if (authButtonState === AUTH_DISABLED) {
      authGlobal.tryAuthentication().then((loggedIn) => {
        setAuthButtonState(loggedIn ? AUTH_LOGOUT : AUTH_LOGIN);
      });
    } 

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div> Display </div>
      <div className='main-controls'>
        <button type='button' onClick={handleClick} disabled = {authButtonState == AUTH_DISABLED}>Log {authButtonState == AUTH_LOGOUT ? "Out" : "In"} </button>
        <LoginPopup isVisible={showLoginPopup}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In code above `tryAuthentication` is async and has 3 paths: credentials are in local storage, credentials are in URL (just logged in with external app) or there is nothing to log in with.

My  problem is that, in second case, button doesn't change to "Log Out". State is never updated but `then()` calls `setAuthButtonState()` correctly.

Putting that branch in `useEffect()` helps but I don't know why.
Shouldn't `then()` queue another rerender with new state without `UseEffect()`?

Comment: `if (authButtonState === AUTH_DISABLED)` is happening outside of `handleClick`. Is this wanted?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to set button to active as log in or log out. It should be outside of click event

Comment: Then it's a side effect on render. As you pointed it out, it needs to be inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: Yes but why? From what I understand under the hood is just queue. Why isn't it rerendering then?

Comment: Did you try forcing a re-render explicitly after the state update?

Comment: How do you do that in function/hooks?
I know in class there is forceUpdate() but there isn't anything like this for functions

Comment: @Derag The [official documentation](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure#side-effects-unintended-consequences) tells you explicitly not to have side effects on render. I don't know enough of the internal mechanics of React to explain precisely why it doesn't work if you still do it, but why would you need to know what exactly happen when you don't follow the documentation?

Comment: I will use effects. Just want to know what exactly is causing this so I understand better what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've refactor your component for better handling of the asynchronous authentication flow.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const AUTH_DISABLED = 0;
const AUTH_LOGIN = 1;
const AUTH_LOGOUT = 2;

function App() {
  const [showLoginPopup, setShowLoginPopup] = useState(false);
  const [authButtonState, setAuthButtonState] = useState(AUTH_DISABLED);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect runs only once after the component mounts
    authGlobal.tryAuthentication().then((loggedIn) => {
      setAuthButtonState(loggedIn ? AUTH_LOGOUT : AUTH_LOGIN);
    });
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means it runs once after mount

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (authButtonState === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
      authGlobal.logout().then(() => {
        setAuthButtonState(AUTH_LOGIN);
        setShowLoginPopup(false); // Hide popup on logout
      });
    } else {
      setShowLoginPopup(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div>Display</div>
      <div className="main-controls">
        <button 
          type="button" 
          onClick={handleClick} 
          disabled={authButtonState === AUTH_DISABLED}
        >
          Log {authButtonState === AUTH_LOGOUT ? "Out" : "In"}
        </button>
        {showLoginPopup && <LoginPopup />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, in summary, while it might seem like the then() should queue another re-render with the new state without **useEffect**, in practice, the asynchronous nature of your tryAuthentication function and the way React batches state updates can lead to the issue you observed. Using useEffect provides a more controlled and predictable way to handle side effects and asynchronous operations in functional components.

Comment: But what exactly is an issue here? Shouldn't 'then()' update state and rerender it at some point?

Comment: From my understanding under the hood is just a queue. So that update state should be put on the queue once 'then()' is finishes and rerendered

Comment: In React, when you update the state using setState (like setAuthButtonState in your code), it should indeed schedule an update and cause a re-render of the component. However, when dealing with asynchronous operations like the then() in a promise, the timing of these updates can be less predictable due to React's batching and rendering optimizations.

Comment: In your case, the tryAuthentication() method is called every time the component renders, which may lead to unexpected behavior or multiple calls.

Comment: By using useEffect, you ensure that this asynchronous operation runs only once when the component mounts, leading to more controlled and predictable behavior. This avoids unnecessary re-renders and ensures that the state is updated at the right time after the asynchronous operation completes.

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering a side effect on render. Side effects on render need to be done inside a `useEffect` hook: https://dev.to/hellonehha/what-is-side-effect-in-reactjs-and-how-to-handle-it-39j8

See [the official documentation about this](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure#side-effects-unintended-consequences) too.

Answer (score 0):

In React, state updates are asynchronous, and the component may not re-render immediately after calling `setAuthButtonState`. The `then` callback in your `tryAuthentication` function is likely resolving outside of the React rendering cycle, which means React doesn't immediately recognize the state change.

Here's a modified version of your code

```
const AUTH_DISABLED = 0;
const AUTH_LOGIN = 1;
const AUTH_LOGOUT = 2;

function App() {
  const [showLoginPopup, setShowLoginPopup] = useState(false);
  const [authButtonState, setAuthButtonState] = useState(AUTH_DISABLED);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (authButtonState === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
      authGlobal.logout().then(() => {
        setAuthButtonState(AUTH_LOGIN);
      });
    } else {
      setShowLoginPopup(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authButtonState === AUTH_DISABLED) {
      authGlobal.tryAuthentication().then((loggedIn) => {
        setAuthButtonState(loggedIn ? AUTH_LOGOUT : AUTH_LOGIN);
      });
    }
  }, [authButtonState]); // Run the effect whenever authButtonState changes

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div> Display </div>
      <div className="main-controls">
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} disabled={authButtonState === AUTH_DISABLED}>
          Log {authButtonState === AUTH_LOGOUT ? "Out" : "In"}
        </button>
        <LoginPopup isVisible={showLoginPopup} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But shouldn't it rerender later then? It looks like it isn't rerendering at all. useEffect fixes this I just don't understand mechanism that is blocking version without it

Comment: In React, state updates are asynchronous, and when you call setAuthButtonState, React schedules an update but doesn't guarantee an immediate re-render. The subsequent code after setAuthButtonState continues to execute, and the component may not re-render before that code completes. This is why, in your case, the state is correctly updated, but the UI doesn't reflect the change